# ¿Cómo se realiza un script en RedHat7 para editar lineas especificas de un archivo?

Tags: linux, script, servicio, configuración, red-hat

Hace unos dias me enseñaron a agilizar algunas tareas en Linux por medio de scripts, por consiguiente quise hacer un script para instalar en este caso el servicio http, entonces escribí un script asi

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install httpd -y

cat >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf <<EOF
ServerName servidor.example.com:80
EOF
```

Hasta ahi el codigo iria bien en el caso de editar el archivo para que tome el nombre de mi maquina, pero el problema es que el comando "cat >>" añade al final del archivo la linea que escribí pero yo quiero es que edite la linea original en ese caso la linea 95
¿Hay alguna manera de hacer que la linea de mi script se escriba en la linea que yo deseo de un archivo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Tu script podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
yum install httpd -y

sed -i.bak "95s/.*/ServerName servidor.example.com:80/" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

## Explicación:

`sed` recibe una cadena con un patrón específico. El `-i` le dice de cambiar el fichero original. Sin ello, no lo cambia sino simplemente escribe el fichero modificado al terminal. Y si le pasas argumento al `-i` (como en este caso `-i.bak`), te hará una copia de seguridad usando el mismo nombre pero con la extension `.bak`: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.bak`.

**Direcciones ([Addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses)):**

El primer valor de la cadena es `95`, que le indica a `sed` la dirección o la posición del cursor en el archivo que estás modificando. En este caso es la línea 95, según lo que especificas en tu pregunta.

**Comando `s` ([`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)):**

Tal vez sea el comando más usado en `sed`. Es la inicial de `substitute` (reemplazo), y le indica a `sed` que se realizará una tarea de reemplazo. El formato de este comando es:

```sh
"s/regexp/reemplazo/flags"
```

donde `regexp` es una expresión regular que representa el texto a ser reemplazado, y `reemplazo` será el texto nuevo que será escrito en lugar de `regexp`. `flags` son modificadores para indicar el tipo de reemplazo (puedes leer un poco más en la documentación).

En este caso la expresión regular que he usado es: `.*` que indica una búsqueda de cualquier carácter (`.`) (excepto salto de linea) que aparezcan 0 o más veces (`*`).

El valor de `reemplazo` es el valor que deseas poner en la línea 95: `ServerName servidor.example.com:80`.

Por último, la ruta del archivo donde se realizará la operación: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` se pasa como segundo argumento a `sed`.

Espero que sea lo que estabas buscando.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que buscaba, muchas gracias nwn